# Is it possible to use this code to create a Sign in with Instagram and how when using Smartface App Studio?

Tags: instagram, smartface.io

Is it possible to use this code to create a Sign in with Instagram and how when using Smartface App Studio?

[The code website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkUuG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your link is broken, I cannot see codes but you can create sign in using Smartface, it is possible if you use plugin or Rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I don't advise that.

This code is writen in HTML and CSS, to use it you would have to create a HTML Page in Smartface, and that would be slower than the "native version" with REST API. And even if you use this code, this is just a button, you would have to implement the logic yourself, so it's better to create a ImageButton using a custom image and add the logic with Smartface's WebClient.

Comment: How I said, yes. But I think that would be way better if you use an Image Button and add an image like this: https://dressmoi.s3.amazonaws.com/images/social/instagram_login.png to it's background. With this approach you can remain native while achieving what you want. By the way, if you create a html page inside your app and use this button, you'll have to learn how Smartface handles communication between native and html environments.